# Adding months inline in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, inline

Is there a way to add months to a date inline on a visualforce page?

Something along {!quote.ExpirationDate.addMonths(3)} is what I was thinking about but I guess the syntax isn't accepted.

Comment: Why not create formula field, adding those months,  and show that in VF page instead of normal field i.e ExpirationDate in your case ?

Comment: I could and that I've already done. This question is really just out of curiosity which can help those limited in the number of available fields in their SF orgs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use MONTH formula to get no of the Month from your date

For printing the name of the month use below

```
{!CASE(MONTH(quote.ExpirationDate), 1, "January", 2, "February", 3, "March",  4, "April",  5, "May",  6, "June", 7, "July", 8, "August", 9, "September", 10, "October", 11, "November", 12, "December", "None")}
```